# SQL bulk update, a field increment

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

So i learned how to do a bulk insert using data from one table as the userId from another table. Now i tried to do the same thing but i have a SQL(ite) error. I took a guess at the syntax and i got it wrong. After i bulk insert into the subscription i want to add 1 to each of the users media count. I have a left join error. How do i correct it?

-edit- I haven't solve this yet. Please help.

NOTE: I am using sqlite ATM but I am switching to mysql or MS sql

```
void updateMediaForSubscribers(long userId, long mediaId, Media_Base.Catagory cat, DateTime currentDate)
{
    command.CommandText =
        "INSERT INTO user_media_subscription (recipientId, mediaId, catagory) " +
        "SELECT watcher, @mediaId, @category " +
        "FROM user_watch WHERE watched=@watched;";
    command.Parameters.Add("@mediaId", DbType.Int64).Value = mediaId;
    command.Parameters.Add("@category", DbType.Int64).Value = cat;
    command.Parameters.Add("@watched", DbType.Int64).Value = userId;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //near "LEFT": syntax error
    command.CommandText =
        "UPDATE user_data SET mediaMsgCount=mediaMsgCount+1 " +
        "LEFT JOIN user_watch AS w ON w.watcher=user_data.userId " +
        "WHERE w.watched=@watched;";
    command.Parameters.Add("@watched", DbType.Int64).Value = userId;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE user_data 
SET mediaMsgCount=mediaMsgCount+1
LEFT JOIN user_watch AS w ON w.watcher=user_data.userId
WHERE w.watched=@watched
```

Looks like it won't work to me, because you're joining in an UPDATE query but without a "FROM" clause, have you tried:

```
UPDATE u
SET u.mediaMsgCount = u.mediaMsgCount+1
FROM user_data u
LEFT JOIN user_watch AS w ON w.watcher=u.userId
WHERE w.watched=@watched
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE user_data 
SET mediaMsgCount = u.mediaMsgCount + 1 
FROM user_data u LEFT OUTER JOIN user_watch w ON w.watcher = u.userId 
WHERE w.watched=@watched
```

Honestly, I'm not really sure why you're using a left outer join since the update is dependant on user_watch... might want to change the "LEFT OUTER JOIN" to an "INNER JOIN".

Also, its a good idea to prefix your table name with the owner, I.E. dbo.user_data ... if you dont do that then sql server has to do a lookup.

Comment: outer join!?! left join is an outer join?
i copied pasted your code in and i get an error near FROM (syntax). i changed user_data u to user_data AS u and still no luck. It looks like i cant use FROM after SET. I am currently using SQLite which pretty much uses the same syntax. I wonder whats incorrect about this? i took a complete guess when i wrote the original.